# How to passing a variable from pug to JS function

Tags: javascript, pug

I am doing a JS function. that retrieve the variable from pub. 
 What is the syntax should I put in.

i tried `${room.roomName}` but it doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```
each room in rooms
   button(onclick="confirm(`${room.roomName}`)")= room.roomName
```

The error is: room is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not too pretentious, you can easily get away with:

```
each room in rooms
   button(onclick="confirm(`${this.innerText}`)")= room.roomName
```